# In swift, is there a way to log into a website with a token gotten with OAuth2 library?

Tags: swift, oauth, oauth-2.0

is there someone who can help me with the OAuth2 library in swift
I'm doing that to handle the end of OAuth

```
appDelegate.oauth2!.afterAuthorizeOrFail = { authParameters, error in
        let formatter = DateFormatter()
        formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
        let myString = formatter.string(from: appDelegate.oauth2!.accessTokenExpiry!)
        print("t \(appDelegate.oauth2!.accessToken)")
        print("td \(myString)")
        //login me here with oauth2.accessToken

}
```

In this block I want to log into my website with an url like that :
`"http://my-website.com/authme.php?token=\(oauth2!.accessToken!)"`

I've try webview.load and no success but if I do the request in another function evrything works like a charm

Thank in advance

EDIT More info

I think it is due to the fact that afterAuthorizeOrFail seems to be called in background

Here is how afterAuthorizeOrFail is called didFail and didAuthorize which only differences are the arguments of the function in those methods

```
public final func didFail(with error: OAuth2Error?) {
        var finalError = error
        if let error = finalError {
            logger?.debug("OAuth2", msg: "\(error)")
        }
        else {
            finalError = OAuth2Error.requestCancelled
        }
        callOnMainThread() {
            self.didAuthorizeOrFail?(nil, finalError)
            self.didAuthorizeOrFail = nil
            self.internalAfterAuthorizeOrFail?(true, finalError)
            self.afterAuthorizeOrFail?(nil, finalError)
        }
    }
```

Here is the source file with this method
https://github.com/p2/OAuth2/blob/master/Sources/Base/OAuth2Base.swift

and callOnMainThread is that:

```
public func callOnMainThread(_ callback: (() -> Void)) {
    if Thread.isMainThread {
        callback()
    }
    else {
        DispatchQueue.main.sync(execute: callback)
    }
}
```

Here is the source file with this method
https://github.com/p2/OAuth2/blob/master/Sources/Base/OAuth2Requestable.swift

And here is how I do the request

```
  let requrl=URL(string: "http://my-website.com/authme.php?token=\(oauth2!.accessToken!)")
     do{
        let request = try URLRequest(url: requrl!,method: .post)
        self.webView!.load(request)
     }catch let error {
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
       print("ERROR loading site \(error)")
     }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I used a wrong WKWebview (not the one on the storyboard)
Changing that fix my issue